# How to manually reset the offset of an mp4 video created from m4s files?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mpeg-dash

I'm building a service that combine `.m4s` files (from a dash stream) to a `mp4` video.
I have some sample `m4s` files from a random point in time of a stream,
using `ffmpeg` on those file + the init file does the job.

```
cat init.mp4 032.m4s 033.m4s 034.m4s > output.mp4
```

I have tried concating the `m4s` files to the `mp4` init file and I manage to play the video,
but there is an offset from the encoded video segments.

I guess `ffmpeg` does reset that somehow, and I was wondering how can I reset that offset as well?
Having a little bit of experience with `dash`, I know that there is a field name `presentationTimeOffset` that is responsible to set the offset.

Answer (score 0):

No. The presentationTimeOffset is already written in each m4s.